# bash add property using variable with jq

Tags: bash, quoting, variable, jq

To add a property to a JSON text I manage to use

```
result=$(jq -c '.docs[0] + { "value": "someValue" }'<<<"$fileContent")
```

But if I want to replace "someValue" by a variable:

```
result=$(jq -c '.docs[0] + { "value": ($value) }'<<<"$fileContent")
```

This gives me

```
jq: error: value/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
.docs[0] + { "value": ($value) }
jq: 1 compile error
```

I also tried without braces `$value` and inside brackets `[$value]` without success.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `jq` expression is within single quotes. This stops `$value` from being expanded by the shell.

Instead, use `jq` with `--arg` to give a `jq` variable the JSON encoded value of the shell variable:

```
result=$(jq --arg value "$value" -c '.docs[0] + { "value": $value }' <<<"$fileContent")
```

Comment: Late to the game, but, how would one surround with double quotes the content of value? Using \" doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: @TekiusFanatikus `jq` should add the quotes if they are needed. If you have value that is _already_ a JSON encoded thing, use `--jsonarg` in place of `--arg`.