# How to parse and add content to json using bash?

Tags: bash, json, jq

I am following the ideas from the stackexchange articles below

- here to select and delete an element [Delete Element](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/700580/how-to-remove-a-specific-json-object-from-a-file)
- here to append an element: [Add New Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42245288/add-new-element-to-existing-json-array-with-jq)

but I am having problems with quotes when selecting and adding.

this is my sample json file

```
{
  "options": [
    {
      "label": "22",
      "value": "2022"
    },
    {
      "label": "23",
      "value": "2023"
    }
  ]
}
```

and this is my test bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

previous_year=$(date --date="$(date +'%Y') - 1 year" +%Y)
last_year=$((previous_year + 31))
label=$((last_year -2000))

echo ${last_year}

jq 'del(.options[]? | select(.label == \"${previous_year}\"))' temp.json
jq '.options += [{
      "label": '${label}',
      "value": '${last_year}'
    }]' temp.json
```

If I run the bash script with this sample file I get
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER (Unix shell quoting issues?) at , line 1:
del(.options[]? | select(.label == "${previous_year}"))
jq: 1 compile error

If I remove the " it runs but don't find anything to delete because it looks without the quotes.
It also add the element to the array but without quotes.

How can I do it?

- find the element with quotes
- add element with quotes

The expected result (what I want to achieve) is

```
{
  "options": [
    {
      "label": "23",
      "value": "2023"
    },
    {
      "label": "53",
      "value": "2053"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: [Use `--arg`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/371473) for the variables ... btw, your `del` command should select on `value` not `label`

Comment: The problem is that `previous_year` etc are all bash variables, not jq variables; you need to copy them into jq variables with `--arg`. See ["Passing bash variable to jq" on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40027395/passing-bash-variable-to-jq).

Comment: I see.  But isn't a way to use variables defined in the script rather then using arg passed variables?

Comment: Uh, why would you want to do that? You _could_ create the `jq` query expression in double quotes and then have your variables interpolated, but this has serious robustness issues if one of the variables is empty or contains weird quoting etc. In the limit, you are opening up yourself to a "little Bobby Tables" attack. Just go with the standard solution.

Comment: Because this is a part that will be included in a build script to update some json files used to mock some responses.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the correct values in the shell variables `label`, `last_year`, and `previous_year` and that you want to delete all entries in the `options` array with the `value` value `$previous_year`, and add a new entry with the `label` value `$label` and `value` value `$last_year`.

```bash
jq  --arg add_label "$label" \
    --arg add_value "$last_year" \
    --arg del_value "$previous_year" '
    del(.options[]? | select(.value == $del_value)) |
    .options += [{ label: $add_label, value: $add_value }]' file
```

This correctly combines the two operations in a single invocation of `jq`.

The command instantiates three internal `jq` string variables with values taken from the shell variables that you have previously created. Using `--arg` to create internal string variables from shell variables ensures that the values are correctly encoded (this avoids code injection vulnerabilities).

As in your code, I use `.options[]?` rather than just `.options[]` to avoid an error if the `options` array does not exist.  If it does exist, any entry with a `value` value of `$del_value` (an internal variable with the value from the shell variable `previous_year`) is deleted.  You tried to select using the `label`, but I believe this might have been a typo.

The (possibly) modified document is passed on to the next stage, which adds a new element to the `options` array.  If the array did not previously exist, this would create it with a single element.

Also note that `jq` does not do in-place editing, which means you will need to redirect the output of the above command to a new name and then replace the original file with that new file.  Alternatively, use GNU `sponge`:

```bash
jq ...as above... file | sponge file
```

(Assuming your file is called `file`.)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
file=temp.json
now="$(date)"
previous_year=$(date --date="$(date +'%Y') - 1 year" +%Y)
last_year=$((previous_year + 31))
label=$((last_year -2000))
echo "==============================================================================================================="
echo "| Started parsing json file at script at: $file"
echo "| Started at:                             $now"
echo "| previous year is:                       $previous_year"
echo "| last year to be at json array is:       $last_year"
echo "| label assigned to the last year :       $label"
echo "==============================================================================================================="

if cat $file | grep $previous_year
then
  jq --arg key "$previous_year" 'del(.options[] | select(.value == $key))' $file >> new.json
  jq --arg key "$label" --arg val "$last_year" '.options += [{
        "label": $key,
        "value": $val
      }]' new.json >> new2.json
  mv new2.json $file
  rm new.json
  echo "last year found and parsed"  
else
  echo "nothing to be done"
fi

now="$(date)"
echo "==============================================================================================================="
echo "| Ended script at: $now"
echo "==============================================================================================================="
´´´
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You also want to avoid the [useless `cat`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html) and quote `"$file"` everywhere.